# ASP.Net Download file not working in IE8

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with downloading an `.xls` file from server. I am able to download the file in local system. But unable to do it from the test server. I can download the file from test server using firefox. But unable to do it from IE 7/8.

I can download the file on local system using IE and firefox. But downloading from remote server is not working from ie 7/8.

What happens in ie is Simply page gets postback but no download window.

Whats the problem? Do I need I to change any settings or any problem.

I tried both attachment and inline options with `response.addheader` And content type as octect stream and vnd.xls.

These options are working perfectly on firefox and ie 7/8 on local server but from remote server only firefox able to download.

Please check my code once.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & compName)
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" & compName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

But the thing I did was to make some setting changes in IE.

Make these settings.

> Go to IE- Tools-> Internet Options.
>
> Select Internet Zone. Click Custom Level.
>
> In Downloads Section. Enable Automatic prompting for downloads

Comment: Thanks for all ur answers. Hope this may useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `Response.Write()` with `StringBuilder.Append()` to append all content in string builder.Then write the content in webpage.It will be work.

you may refer this Link:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1573064.aspx/1?How+to+export+html+table+to+excel+using+asp+net+c+

Hope this may helpful..

Comment: `string FilePath = MapPath("AppFile/sample.xls");` try to use like this thats it.

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work      Since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
  string FilePath = MapPath("AppFile/MyCV.pdf");
  Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
  Response.End();
}
```